# Allow Multiple File Formats Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

i want to allow users to upload .png / .jpg / .PNG / .gif

The rule am using now only allows .png :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UujZ.png

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image\\.png` is not a content type.

```
request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg')
     || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png')
     || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/gif')
```

(Please do not upload screenshots but show text instead.)